# ios dev - UIWebView cant open local files inside a folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to open a file (index.html) in a `UIWebView`. it's everything ok when the file is in the root and is loaded this way:

```
[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

But when I put the inDirectory parameter:

```
[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"files"]]]];
```

I get this error:

> ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL
>   initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

I already checked my target and the file is listed at the "Copy Bundle Resources" list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All resources loaded into the bundle get flattened into a single directory when the app is built.

You just need to use:

```
NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"html"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:bundleURL];

[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

With the following directory structure in Xcode (test.html is in the Resources group):

[image]

And if you look in the package app when its installed in the simulator it looks like:

[image]

Any "groups" or folders you have in Xcode are removed. (Note test.html is in the root with everything else)

Bottom line, when loading resources out of the bundle keep it simple and use `URLForResource:withExtension:`